# Volley TimeOutError. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, android-volley

resulta que estoy trabajando con volley. Cuando quiero llenar un Recyclerview resulta que me aparece el error descrito en el titulo, estuve leyendo y sé que es por el tiempo de respuesta entre la aplicación y servidor (en este caso), probé distintas soluciones que al final me terminaron afectado al proyecto (por ejemplo se me cerraban). Si necesitan alguna otra parte del codigo me lo hacen saber, aunque con este debería bastar porque sé que se usa esta parte del codigo para implementar lo de los tiempos.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

        listaProducto = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerProducto = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.listaTodasRec);
        recyclerProducto.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        recyclerProducto.setHasFixedSize(true);

        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        cargarWebService();

        return vista;
    }

    private void cargarWebService() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progress.setMessage("Buscando productos..");
        progress.show();

        String url = "http://192.169.1.40:7777/Proyecto/buscartodas.php";

        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se puede conectar, error: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println();
        Log.d("Error: ", error.toString());
        progress.hide();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Productos productos= null;
        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("productos");

        try{
            for (int i = 0; i<json.length();i++)
            {
                productos= new Productos();
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                productos.setIdProducto(jsonObject.optInt("id_prod"));
                productos.setNombreProducto(jsonObject.optString("nomb_prod"));
                productos.setPieProducto(jsonObject.optString("pie_prod"));

                listaProductos.add(productos);
            }
            progress.hide();
            ProductosAdapters adapters = new ProductosAdapters (listaProductos);
            recyclerProducto.setAdapter(adapters);
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido conectar con el servidor" + " " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progress.hide();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Veo que haces la petición de manera local, tienes el apache habilitado para que Volley se pueda conectar con tu Web-Service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recuerdo haber tenido en el pasado un problema parecido y lo resolví del siguiente modo:

1. Declarando una constante `MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`

En mi caso dicha constante está en mi clase `Constants` la cual importo luego donde las necesite. Le he dado un valor de `15000`:

```
public class Constants {

    public static final int MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 15000;

    //...
}
```

2. Establecer una *política de reintentos*  en mi petición Volley mediante el método `setRetryPolicy` en la que uso mi constante.

   ```
   jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
           MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
           DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
           DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
   ```

Esto habría que hacerlo **antes de añadir la petición a la cola**, o sea, antes de esta línea:

```
    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Desde entonces no he vuelto a tener problemas de timeout.

Si aún así no funciona, conviene que verifiques que no hay ningún problema con la URL `http://192.169.1.40:7777/Proyecto/buscartodas.php`, probándola desde el navegador por ejemplo o revisando los log de errores de PHP.

Si todo está bien de ese lado y sigue sin funcionar, considera aumentar el valor de la constante, al menos para peticiones que sean demasiado extensas. O... considera a optimizar el código en el servidor o la base de datos. A veces las respuestas son lentas porque el código PHP no está optimizado, o porque los índices en la base de datos no son los adecuados, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo !!!!! Me sirvió a la perfección y muy bien explicado por cierto, te daría muchos likes pero solo puedo darte uno jajaja, de verdad estoy muy agradecido ! :D